# Mutually exclusive command line options

Tags: python, getopt

```
def parseCommandLine(argv=[]):
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(
            sys.argv[1:],
            "h:i:o:p:v", 
            ["help","ifile=","ofile=","fcsname=","verbose"])
    except getopt.GetoptError,msg:
        printUsage()
        print "-E-Badly formed command line vishal!"
        print "  ",msg
        sys.exit(1)

    #Processing command line arguments
    for opt, arg in opts:
        opt= opt.lower()
            # Help
        if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
            printUsage()
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
            inputfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
            outputfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-p", "--fcsname"):
            FCSNAME = arg

        if opt in ("-v", "--verbose"):
            VERBOSE = 1 



    print 'Input file is "', inputfile
    print 'Output file is "', outputfile
    print 'PCS NAME is "', FCSNAME
            # Verbose
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath('inputfile')) and os.access(arg, os.R_OK):
        print "-E-File is given as input and it is readable"
        fcsprojectlistfile(inputfile)                           
    else:
        print "FCS_NAME  given as input", 
        sys.exit(1)


    return 0
```

Everything is working fine...
getting output as

```
./aaa_scr -i list -o sharma -p pcs

Input file is " list
Output file is " sharma
PCS NAME is " pcs
```

PCS_NAME  given as input

but last output is wrong.. **list** is  valid file that exists at current working directory. It should have printed.. 
print "-E-File is given as input and it is readable

I want to achieve soming like if `-i` option and file is present   or `-p` and `fcsname` is present..

It should have condition only one is valid at one time either (`-i` or `-p`)  and if `-i` is present with file name check. If file is valid and fire another function, otherwise check if `-p` is present with `pcsname` and fire another function, and if both are present flag error.

Comment: Edit to have clear question. I can guess what you want to say in last 2 paragraphs but I'm not sure.

Comment: I want to achieve something like if -i option and "ifile" is present or -p and fcsname is present..at input, then it is invalid condition.

If -i is present with "ifile". If file is valid the print"valid file"  , otherwise in else part it will check if -p is present with pcsname and if both are present flag error.

Comment: You're using the literal string `'inputfile'` in your check

Comment: even if i sue it this way it was not working...  if os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath(inputfile))

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `argparse` instead of `optparse`, which allows you to write less code.

`argparse` offers a method to handle [mutual exclusion](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#mutual-exclusion) of command-line parameters, but since you want to use the `-p` parameter if and only if the `-i` parameter does not "binds" to a readable file, this method would not help you.

So here is an example of what you can do with `argparse` to solve your problem:

```
import argparse
import os
import sys

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--ifile', type=argparse.FileType('r'), help='Input file')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--ofile', help='Output file')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--fcsname', help='PCS name')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', help='Enable verbose mode')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.v:
    VERBOSE = True

if args.o:
    print("Output file is: {}".format(args.o))

if args.i:
    print("Input file is: {}".format(args.i.name))
    # call a function with args.i in parameter
elif args.p:
    print("FCS name is: {}".format(args.p))
    # call a function with args.p in parameter
else:
    print("You must indicate either a input file or a FCS name.")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: I have python 2.6 dont have argparse in it..  -E-Import statements : No module named argparse

Comment: ``argparse`` is part of the standard library since Python 2.7, but you can install it on 2.6 from PyPi. First, you have to install "pip" and then do: ``pip install argparse``